# High Resolution Image Viewer

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, html, cordova

Is there any library in Objective-C (free or paid) that I can use for displaying huge image maps done from lets say 512x512 pixel tiles (somehow as google maps does it)?

Or maybe there is an HTML5/Javascript library that I can use along with PhoneGap to get this functionality.

Each tile is an jpeg/png and are stored on the local device or in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

There is an apple Demo application which does exactly what you want:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

In this Demo the tile-size is 256x256 but you can easily adjust the code to meet your requirements.